# How to determine deleted message ID in Skype

Tags: php, botframework

When a message sent to Skype bot it has and "id" field in payload.

When later user, who sent initial message, deletes this message, another event comes. Message is referenced there by 2 identifiers, but none of them matches initial message's ID.

Example initial message payload (dumped from PHP array):

```
Array
(
    [text] => <quote author="BotSkypeId" authorname="The Bot That Is Offline" conversation="28:BotSkypeId" timestamp="1508405079"><legacyquote>[19/10/2017 12:24:38] The Bot That Is Offline: </legacyquote>ok<legacyquote>

&lt;&lt;&lt; </legacyquote></quote>
    [type] => message
    [timestamp] => 2017-10-19T09:31:24.035Z
    [id] => 1508405483924
    [channelId] => skype
    [serviceUrl] => https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/
    [from] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29:mySkypeId
            [name] => Mikhail Vasilyev
        )

    [conversation] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29:mySkypeId
        )

    [recipient] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28:BotSkypeId
            [name] => The Bot That Is Offline
        )

    [entities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [locale] => en-US
                    [country] => RU
                    [platform] => Web
                    [type] => clientInfo
                )

        )

    [channelData] => Array
        (
            [text] => <quote author="BotSkypeId" authorname="The Bot That Is Offline" conversation="28:BotSkypeId" timestamp="1508405079"><legacyquote>[19/10/2017 12:24:38] The Bot That Is Offline: </legacyquote>ok<legacyquote>

&lt;&lt;&lt; </legacyquote></quote>
        )

)
```

Payload sent when previous message deleted:

```
Array
(
    [text] => Edited previous message: <e_m ts="1508405485" ts_ms="1508405483928" a="vasilyev.mikhail" t="61"></e_m>
    [type] => message
    [timestamp] => 2017-10-19T09:43:32.302Z
    [localTimestamp] => 2017-10-19T12:43:32.302+03:00
    [id] => 1508406212195
    [channelId] => skype
    [serviceUrl] => https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/
    [from] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29:mySkypeId
            [name] => Mikhail Vasilyev
        )

    [conversation] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29:mySkypeId
        )

    [recipient] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28:BotSkypeId
            [name] => The Bot That Is Offline
        )

    [entities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [locale] => en-US
                    [country] => UA
                    [platform] => Mac
                    [type] => clientInfo
                )

        )

    [channelData] => Array
        (
            [text] => Edited previous message: <e_m ts="1508405485" ts_ms="1508405483928" a="vasilyev.mikhail" t="61"/>
        )

)
```

I noticed that ts="1508405485" is very close to [id] => 1508405483924, but this can't be reference.